# Javascript Object.keys issue

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

When I run the following code:

```
var object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var object2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

var obj1Keys = Object.keys(object1);
var obj2Keys = Object.keys(object2);
console.log(obj2Keys[0] in obj1Keys);
```

The console logs false.  Clearly both object1 and object2 have property 'b'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `in` is used for looping through the object. If you write `objKeys[objKeys[0]]` then you get the result you are looking for

Comment: You don't need all the object faff, `"b" in ["b"]` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `includes()` method instead.

```
console.log(obj1Keys.includes(obj2Keys[0]));
```

This is because the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) works on object keys. The "keys" to an array are number indices (`0`, `1`, etc), not their values

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the object, not the array with the keys for checking and [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). This check the keys of the object and arrays have indices and length property.

If you like to take the array with the keys, cou could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var object1 = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    object2 = { b: 4, c: 3 },
    obj1Keys = Object.keys(object1),
    obj2Keys = Object.keys(object2);

console.log(obj2Keys[0] in object1);
console.log(obj1Keys.includes(obj2Keys[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

By asking if `obj2Keys[0] in obj1Keys`, you're asking whether `'b'` is a key of `['a', 'b']`.  It's not.  It's a **value** of `['a', 'b']`.  You could check like this instead:

```
obj1Keys.includes(objKeys[0])
```